# Find related element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on this DOM tree below when a comment reply button is clicked I need to use `$(this)` and then navigate to the next comment textarea `.task-modal-cmt-reply-textarea`

I am using jQuery and tried to use `.parent().parent().closest('.task-modal-cmt-reply-textarea')` and a few other combination without luck so far.

Can someone show me an efficient way to get this element into a var?

[image]

---

**What I am trying to accomplish...**

I have a click even on a comment reply button which insert a reply form into the DOM below a parent comment when the reply button is clicked using...

```
$document.on('click', '.cmt-reply-btn', function(e) {}
```

In this click event the reply form is put into the DOM with...

```
$parentCmtDomNode.after(cmtReplyFormTemplateHtml);
```

After the form is in the DOM I try to attach a jQuery plugin to it for @mention style capability using...

```
$('.task-modal-cmt-reply-textarea').mentionsInput({});
```

**The problem**

The @mention library works for the 1st clicked on comment form but all other reply forms do not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another way to get a reference to that element, would be to do this:

`var el = $(this).parent().parent().next().find('.task-modal-cmt-reply-textarea').eq(0);`

note that the eq(0) just gives a single object back instead of an array with one element, which may or may not be necessary depending on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks this is the only one I got to work so far.  It also solved my issue described at the end of my post above thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var textarea_value=$(this).closest('.Activity-item').next('.Activity-item').find('form .task-model-cmt-reply-textarea').val();
```

or if its related with `data-activityid = "12"` so you can use

```
$(document).on('click','.cmt-reply-btn',function(){
   var textarea_value = $(form[data-comment-parent-id = "'+$(this).attr('data-activityid')+' .task-modal-cmt-reply-textarea"]).val();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do another .parent(), the two parent() you did only bring you up to the level of class "Activity-item Activity-comment" with data-activity-id = 12. Do another parent and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient way would be to use the [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) api from jQuery then followed by your .closests

```
.parents('div')
```

> The .parents() and .parent() methods are similar, except that the latter only travels a single level up the DOM tree. Also, $( "html" ).parent() method returns a set containing document whereas $( "html" ).parents() returns an empty set.

Then add the following sub selector to your closest chain.

```
.closest('textarea[name=^"task-modal-cmt-textarea"]')
```

This looks for the closest textarea with the name starting with task-modal-cmt-textarea. This is more efficient than what you have as this will eliminate any lookups on non textarea elements then it will only filter out the textareas that have that particular name.

EDIT: Updated Answer to the OP's recent edit.

```
$('.task-modal-cmt-reply-textarea').mentionsInput({});
```

This will select all of the ".task-modal-cmt-reply-textarea" that are on the screen at the time, it will not account for future ones. To achieve what you are looking for you should put a sub selector on this chain to allow it to attach to the newest form that was created.

```
$('.task-modal-cmt-reply-textarea',$($parentCmtDomNode).next('textarea')).mentionsInput({});
```

This should be placed after the

```
$parentCmtDomNode.after(cmtReplyFormTemplateHtml);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var txt_html = $(this).parents('.Activity').children("textarea:first").html();

var txt_val = $(this).parents('.Activity').children("textarea:first").val();
```

In the parents() function you need to use the closest parent class/ id.

Answer (score 1):

```
var el = $(this).parents('.Activity-item').next().find('.task-modal-cmt-reply-textarea').eq(0);
```